# SCORM and user accounts

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Consider an online learning web app where each client can create courses that they can share to a list of users, and each course contains a number of pedagogical activities, organized in a very specific way. The app stores the activity log of each user in a given format, that allows to compute the progress on each activity (which is more complex than a 0-100% score).

Now, if a client wants to include such a course on their LMS, it will have to be exported as a SCORM object, and I'm trying to figure out how to do that, if it's possible.

Here are my questions:

- When a learner opens the course on the LMS, is it possible to just give it an `iframe` with a link to the course on the original app? or does the SCORM object need to be a self-sufficient package that cannot make calls to the app's server?
- Will the learner be authenticated on the app?

  - If the learner IS authenticated, the app won't need to "read" any progress/status data because it will log everything for itself, but it will need to send such information to the LMS through the API: is that correct?
  - If the learner IS NOT authenticated, the app needs to provide a way to reproduce the experience of an authenticated user based on a data model (CMI?) that represents the progress of the user: is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Q1/Q2: you can do a IFRAME, new window/tab or popup.  The Package should have everything it needs to work i.e. Shareable Content Object.

Q3/Q4/Q5: They would be Authenticated to the LMS.  SCORM doesn't offer any authorization calls, since typically you'd need to be on the LMS to see it.  You do have the student id, and name available to you per the SCORM Specification.  Name can be a email, or a username - its up to how the LMS does it.  For attempting to manage users within a SCO I would say you'd have to enable some other cross-domain API but that would be outside the scope of SCORM and would take the "Shareable" part and throw it out.

I have a lot of info down on my github project - https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki

The xAPI or TinCan offers OAuth but all the communication would be sent to a endpoint you specify, or the endpoint specified in content you are serving.  This doesn't communicate with the LMS the way SCORM does.  Its based off of ActivityStreams like you see with Social Media.